# Keep dialog div where I put it

Tags: jquery, dom, dialog

Is there any way to have jQuery [UI] make a [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) in-place? Or move it back easily and have it work?

[YUI2's Panel](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/panel-resize_source.html) gave you the freedom to do this, it assumed you knew what you were doing and left the markup exactly where you put it.
But now that I've moved to using simpler jQuery I noticed a restriction; jQuery UI seems to only make dialogs directly under `body`.

---

Consider [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/PCJTg/);
Say you want to use divs as a way of namespacing css.
Write a stylesheet pertinent to a feature by prefixing all the selectors with `.className`, and have the markup inside a div with `class="className"`.

```html
Some

<div class="sectiona">
    <div class="popup" title="A popup">
        This text should be <span class="emphasis">blue</span>
    </div>
</div>

irrelevant

<div class="sectionb">
    <div class="popup" title="B popup">
        This text should be <span class="emphasis">red</span>
    </div>
</div>

content

<script>$(function() { $('.popup').dialog(); });</script>
```

```css
.emphasis {
    color : yellow;
}

.sectiona .emphasis {
    color : blue;
}

.sectionb .emphasis {
    color : red;
}
```

The popup divs (`.popup`) will be moved to body, losing all the css! (obviously would be more complex in real life).
Since all dialogs/panels are positioned absolutely, and the divs I want them kept in have a static position and are children of the body it [wouldn't make any difference at all to keep them there](http://jsfiddle.net/MCmfJ/2/).

*Don't take this css namespacing technique (if that's even correct phrasing) as the only reason for wanting this, I'm sure there are other use cases*

Comment: So the short version of this question is: **"jQuery UI moves the dialog element from its initial location to `body`, making it an immediate child. Is there a way to stop it from doing that?"** Is that right?

Comment: Or move it back after it does that blunder. That's what the first line was boiling down to, before expanding later. If there's a flag I can pass to `dialog()`, fantastic, otherwise a workaround that doesn't break things would be usable.

Comment: @ Hashbrown: You'll find that people are much more interested in helping people who don't rant. Stop calling it a "blunder" and such, and remember how much jQuery and jQuery UI **save you time**. So they made a choice you disagree with (and I do too), no need to go on about it.

Comment: Sorry if it offended, I didn't consider 'blunder' that powerful a word. It just did something I didn't want, and gave me no choice to have it not do it. It's an accident, and its undesirable => blunder? It was just my use of words to describe it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [`appendTo`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo) option, you will need to specify it for each separate popup :

```
// HTML
// added a common "section" class to your divs
Some
<div class="section sectiona">
    <div class="popup" title="A popup">This text should be <span class="emphasis">blue</span>
    </div>
</div>
irrelevant
<div class="section sectionb">
    <div class="popup" title="B popup">This text should be <span class="emphasis">red</span>
    </div>
</div>
content

// javascript
$('.section').each(function () {
    $(this).find('.popup').dialog({
        appendTo: this
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47Se3/)

Comment: Is this a [feature of a newer](http://jsfiddle.net/47Se3/1/) jQuery? Because the API says that the appendTo option [is a selector](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo), not element

Comment: You're right : http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/ .  I just checked the doc to see if there was an option, didn't check when it appeared. Can you upgrade to jquery-ui >= 1.10 ?

Comment: upgrading will be better than hacking an id into things to give `appendTo` a `#` selector. upvote for going the extra mile. jQuery should update the docs, no?